# How can I sleep with responsive context cancelation?

Tags: go

In Go, I want to `time.Sleep` for some time (e.g. waiting between retries), but want to return quickly if the context gets canceled (not just from a deadline, but also manually).

What is the right or best way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `select` to acheive this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "context"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()
    go func(){
        t := time.Now()
        select{
        case <-ctx.Done(): //context cancelled
        case <-time.After(2 * time.Second): //timeout
        }
        fmt.Printf("here after: %v\n", time.Since(t))
    }()

    cancel() //cancel manually, comment out to see timeout kick in
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("done")

}
```

Here is the [Go-playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/PkXbjNxnRuz)

Comment: [Same comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135239/how-can-i-sleep-with-responsive-context-cancelation#comment132288704_62287775).

Answer (score 12):

You can use `select` as others have mentioned; however, **the other answers have a bug** since `timer.After()` will leak memory if not cleaned up.

```go
func SleepWithContext(ctx context.Context, d time.Duration) {
    timer := time.NewTimer(d)
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        if !timer.Stop() {
            <-timer.C
        }
    case <-timer.C:
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly true. time.After could leak only until the timer is fired. So if you create lots of time.After timers with long durations, and most of the time they don't fire because you select on some other case earlier - then it could become an important leak. Otherwise, for short durations and timeout semantics time.After is totally fine.

Answer (score 7):

The `time.After()` function has this problem:

> The underlying Timer is not recovered by the garbage collector until
> the timer fires. If efficiency is a concern, use NewTimer instead and
> call Timer.Stop if the timer is no longer needed.

It is better to use a `Timer` object and call `Stop()`:

```golang
// Delay returns nil after the specified duration or error if interrupted.
func Delay(ctx context.Context, d time.Duration) error {
    t := time.NewTimer(d)
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        t.Stop()
        return fmt.Errorf("Interrupted")
    case <-t.C:
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I think it is better to return `ctx.Err()`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a `sleepContext` function that you can use instead of `time.Sleep`:

```
func sleepContext(ctx context.Context, delay time.Duration) {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
    case <-time.After(delay):
    }
}
```

And some sample usage ([full runnable code on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OLBrjeKKqUC7)):

```
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    fmt.Println(time.Now())
    sleepContext(ctx, 1*time.Second)
    fmt.Println(time.Now())

    ctxTimeout, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 500*time.Millisecond)
    sleepContext(ctxTimeout, 1*time.Second)
    cancel()
    fmt.Println(time.Now())
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the high-level `time.After` function, you could create an instance of the more low-level `time.Timer` type, which you could stop as soon as cancellation is detected. That way, you'd kill the goroutine used under the hood by the `time.Timer` as early as possible. [Egon Elbre mentioned this approach in his talk at GopherCon Europe 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qq3gu0JQ0yU&t=20m17s).

Comment: Or use `time.AfterFunc` instead of `time.After`.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your usecase `select{}` is not needed. You can just replace `time.Sleep(5)`
with

```
sleep, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second*5)
defer cancel()
<-sleep.Done()
```

`<-sleep.Done()` waits 5 seconds or until the parent `ctx` gets canceled, whichever happens first.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do something similar by combining a CancelContext with a TimeoutContext...

Here is the sample code:

```
cancelCtx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
defer cancel()
// The program "sleeps" for 5 seconds.
timeoutCtx, _ := context.WithTimeout(cancelCtx, 5*time.Second)
select {
case <-timeoutCtx.Done():
    if cancelCtx.Err() != nil {
        log.Printf("Context cancelled")
    }
}
```

In [this repo](https://github.com/skryde/yac/blob/master/main.go) you can find the complete usage of the above code. Sorry for my short answer, I didn't turned on the computer yet, and is not that easy to answer from the phone...

Comment: WithCancel followed by WithTimeout is redundant. WithTimeout returns a cancel function as well, which you ignore. That causes a resource leak. Cancel *must* be called.

Comment: I think I didn't know that `context.WithTimeout()` returns a cancel function... But any way this code is pretty simpliffied; in [my code](https://github.com/skryde/yac/blob/master/main.go) I needed to create a WthCancel context in the main goroutine that could cancel multiples `context.WithTimeout` in other goroutines (I'm making a task runner, like a super simpliffied Cron that run tasks every `n` minutes).